After installing Ubuntu 22.04, can't see home router wifi radio, even though adapter works fine!
My laptop works fine with other wifi in other places (even after I installed Ubuntu, 22.04); But somehow it lost vision of my Home Router signal! I run both Windows 10 and Ubuntu on it and both OS don't see it.
Laptop: Dell M6700
Adapter: Broadcom (2.4 Ghz)
Wifi Router: Asus RT-AC1200G+
I'm not Pro in Linux.
Please, where do I need to search for a problem cause?
I repeat: adapter works fine with other wifi signals, I can connect to them. My router works fine too, my phones and Tablets are connected no problems at all!
I don't understand how it can't see radio from router at all! Or how do I check if adapter is seeing the signal?! Any special comands for this in terminal?
If need more detailed info let me know and how do I provide it?
Thank you!

Is your router broadcasting its ESSID?  If not, you wont see it in the scan results, but you can still connect to "hidden network".

Yes, it does broadcasting it's ESSID. I can see it with other devices

gonna go sleep for now, If I need to provide more detailed info please let me know what. I'll do it tomorrow. Thank you!

Check that your router and laptop are using the same band for radio (G vs. N ).  Routers may do both, or just select one.  Any other complications like range extenders?

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

@waltinator How do I provide all this info here (those commands give lots of lines in output..). Do you want to just copy/paste it here? (I don't understand what they mean)

@ubfan1 Router does both g&n
not sure how do I find about Laptop wich one it is using

just for info: I just restarted and loaded my Windows and it works fine! It does see my wifi and connects to it automatically, so there is for sure something on Linux side

Look at channels seen. G is 1-11 (location dependent).

@ubfan1
checked: it lists 1-11

@ubfan1
YOO, man!
I checked on router and it was working on channel 12..
So I just changed it to 1 and checked again on laptop ..
aaannnnd!! it is visible now!

BIG THANK YOU!!!! @ubfan1

The 2.4MHz radio frequency band for wireless covers channels 1-14, but is restricted to channels 1-11 in some countries (e.g. USA).  The country code in the wireless setup should configure the allowed channels.  You may have to select the channel to use in some cases, so select 1, 6, or 11 to avoid frequency overlap (see https://www.engeniustech.com/go-guide-channel-transmit-power-wi-fi-networks-2/ ).  If one device is on channel 12, another device limited to channels 1-11 will not see it.  Set both devices to channels both can see, and try to properly configure the device using a channel outside the allowed set.
